# C++ Function static local, performance?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have a function that must return true of false depending on the value of a member enum representing the type of operator.

I'm wondering what would be the fastest between the following options, as I'm not sure of what implicit optimizations the compiler is going to do, if any.

```
   inline bool isBinaryOper( void ) const // Fastest i assume.
   {
      static const bool arr[] =
      {
         true,  // E_PLUS
         true,  // E_MINUS
         true,  // E_MULTIPLY
         true,  // E_DIVIDE
         false, // E_LPARENT
         false, // E_RPARENT
         false, // E_COMMA
         false  // E_SEMICOLON
      };

      return arr[ size_t( this->_eType ) ]; // Assuming values are valid indexes.
   }
```

Or :

```
   inline bool isBinaryOper( void ) const
   {
      switch( this->_eType )
      {
         case E_PLUS      : return true;
         case E_MINUS     : return true;
         case E_MULTIPLY  : return true;
         case E_DIVIDE    : return true;
         case E_LPARENT   : return false;
         case E_RPARENT   : return false;
         case E_COMMA     : return false;
         case E_SEMICOLON : return false;
         default : ...
      };
   }
```

Or, which I guess is very similar to the previous one :

```
   inline bool isBinaryOper( void ) const
   {
      if      ( this->_eType == E_PLUS  ) return true;
      else if ( this->_eType == E_MINUS ) return true;
      // etc...
   }
```

Which one would be the fastest, and why ?

Comment: You might be able to make this even faster if those `E_` constants were all powers of base-2 and could combine into a bitmask. Then: `return !(this->_eType & (E_LPARENT | E_RPARENT | ...))`

Comment: @tadman Thanks, i'll consider this options, but i'm not sure yet how many operators i'll have but i guess there should be enough bits.

Comment: You could add a boolean field and initialize the operator type when you first set `_eType` once, `inline bool isBinaryOper() const { return _isBinary; }`.

Comment: @BSH That's totally what i need, thanks.

Comment: If you use the array and then later change the enum, e.g. add a new value or re-arrange it, your code will break. The switch statement will either still work for re-arranged values or at least produce a meaningful error if there is a default case. If not, the compiler should issue a warning. So I would use the more maintainable one which is the switch.

Comment: Switching on something named eType always rings a bell concerning design issues. Maybe you could replace the type-switching completely with inheritance?

Comment: @Jens I'm using this for down casting. I was told it's not a good practice indeed, but i havn't found any other proper design for what i need to do.
About maintainability, it's not a problem. This is going to be a source code parser, and i won't be adding new symbols every 2 days, so the extra work of checking that things are ordered properly is acceptable.

Comment: @Virus721 If the data structure (number of symbols) is not subject to change, I would consider the visitor pattern. It was actually invented exactly for this use-case: adding functions working on a syntax tree.

Comment: @Jens I will have a look, thanks.

Comment: @Virus721 You will probably find the course Intermediate Software Design from D. Schmidt interesting: http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs251/. Starting with session 17 (http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs251/lectures/GoF-patterns-parts-1-and-2.pdf), he does a case study to show design patterns for expression trees.

Comment: @Jens In my case i'm using this for a sequence of tokens : `class Token; class OperatorToken : public Token; class LitteralToken : public Token; class IdentifierToken : public Token;`. The base class Token has an enum which i use to determine the sucblass to downcast and access the subclass specific members. For exemple : `if( token->type == E_OPERATOR && static_cast< OperatorToken * >( token )->oper == E_PLUS ) { ...`. I will have a look at this course, thx.

Answer (score 1):

This question strikes me as being an instance of premature optimization, but for what its worth, I'd go with the `switch` statement even though it is likely to be slightly slower, because:

1. You're not going to notice the slowdown.
2. Assuming you fill in the `default:` case, the switch implementation protects you against invalid data or changes to the enum definition, which will simplify debugging.
3. Both gcc and clang (and probably other good compilers) will optimize the switch into either a binary search or a jump table, depending on how the alternatives are ordered and the precise characteristics of the target platform. In neither case will it simply do a linear sequence of checks with each possible value, like the `if ... else if ... else if ...` option, which is almost certainly the slowest.

   That saves you from thinking about how to order the alternatives, particularly since you might need various boolean functions with different orderings. Unless you are an expert in computer architectures, you can reasonably assume that your compiler understands it better.

Comment: Ugh, I hate comments like this. There is nothing at all wrong with understanding what your language compiler is doing under the covers so that you can write more efficient code.

Comment: @JonathanWood: It's precisely because I have some understanding of what my compiler is doing under the covers that I am happy to live with it optimising my code.

Comment: Yes i'm also asking this to know better what's implicitly happening, not only for performance. ANd yes it is premature optimizations, i'll probably save a lot more time on other things, but it doesn't forbid me to ask about it.

Comment: @rici: That doesn't address what I said.

Comment: @Virus721: In that case, look at my point #3 :). Or use the `-S` option to gcc or clang to actually see what code is produced. With your alternatives arranged so that the `true`s are all before the `falses`, you'll probably get two conditional branches, one predictable (out of range) and the other one not. If you rearrange the options so that true and false alternate, you'll probably get a jump table, which is much less predictable but still fast enough.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the default case improves maintainability. I would always prefer that and then optimize later after using a profiler.

Comment: @JonathanWood as a cost-oriented analyst, I have seen over and over that most of the time, any cost saved by knowning/understanding what the compiler is doing under the covers is tenfold wasted when you have to maintain the program. Hence the term "premature optimization" and its epithet "the root of all evil" :D... From a cost analysis standpoint, it is cheaper to develop, profile, than investigating why the bottlenecks exist, then learning about that specific case of your compiler's code generation, then optimizing...

Comment: @Massa: I would expect that it depends on the degree of not optimizing. I don't think there is anything cheaper about writing bad code.

Comment: @Massa: Just because I don't agree with something doesn't mean I'm missing it. Perhaps you missed the point that there are degrees of "unoptimized" and that I put bad code somewhere on that scale.

Comment: @JonathanWood :: I can only read what is written. That is what I have read: "There is nothing at all wrong with understanding what your language compiler is doing under the covers so that you can write more efficient code", "I would expect that it depends on the degree of not optimizing. I don't think there is anything cheaper about writing bad code." My point was: yes, in my somewhat extensive experience, the cost does not depend on the degree of optimizing or not, but mostly on the fact that the optimizing should succeed the initial development, the debugging, and the profiling.

Comment: And my definition of good code is: "it does exactly what it says it does; and it says exactly what it does". :D (no "as efficiently as possible" here, unless it's strictly necessary)

Comment: @Massa: And my definition of good code is code that is clear, does exactly what it needs to do and does it without using excess resources. :P

Comment: @JonathanWood: I completely agree that it is useful and interesting to know what a compiler is likely to do, which is why I gave a broad outline in my answer (branch table or binary search, whichever is judged faster for the architecture). By the way, I have no idea why you think a binary search is impossible for sparse values, but definitely understanding how binary search works is useful for understanding some compilation strategies and certain standard library implementations.

Comment: @rici: It was the jump table that I asked about working with sparse values.

Comment: @JonathanWood: You said "I'm not sure how switch could avoid comparing each item because the items may not be consecutive and how would that approach handle the default case?" A binary search only compares `log k` of the `k` options; if there are lots of options, it will be faster than "comparing each item".

Comment: @rici: Okay, I agree that a binary search works without comparing each and every item (except in the worst case). Either way, I do not believe that a binary search is faster or even as fast as simply using an indexer into an array.

Comment: @JonathanWood: What worst case? Binary search *never* compares more than `log k` items. And I never claimed that it was faster or as fast as using an array; just that it was considerably faster than a naive chain of `if` statements, so that it is not as much slower than array lookup. (Not to mention that array lookup is only practical with a non-sparse enumeration.)

Comment: @rici: In the worst case, a binary search will compare each and every item. At any rate, we're just beating a dead horse now. I've acknowledged that a binary search can do a lookup without comparing each item. I think this discussion has run it's course.

Comment: @JonathanWood do you remember what is a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)? in the worst case, a binary search will compare only to log2(N) items, not to "each and every item"... if you have 1024 items, you'll do **at most ten** comparisons, **never** 1024.

Comment: @Massa: What if there is one item? What if there is two? Why are we arguing over something so simple and obvious?

Comment: @JonathanWood Ha! What a twist! I have no other option than to concede you are correct: the worst cast of a binary search is the `set_size <= 2`, and in that case it's `O(N)`. :D (Oh, wait, `O(N)` where `0 <= N <= 2` is `O(1)`...) Ah, I know why _I_ am arguing over that. Do you? :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the value as an index into an array is considerably faster than a `switch` statement.

Your second and third code blocks would perform about equally. But the first one quickly gets the index and uses it to access the desired array element. That would be my preference; however, you'll probably want to add error checking as well to ensure the argument is within the expected range.

Comment: Do you have figures or reasoning to back up that claim? I don't see that an array lookup would necessarily be faster than a jump table (which is a typical implementation for a dense `switch` statement).

Comment: @Jonathan Wood. Thanks for your answer. I had the design of a hash table in mind for the first option, but i was more concerned about the static local variable. Is there a test performed when entering a function with static local variables initizations or any other implicit things ?

Comment: A typical implementation of an array lookup would simply add the index times the size of each element to the base address of the array. No comparisons or loops needed. The switch or if statements would require comparing each item. The array index would be many times faster.

Comment: @Virus721: There is no performance hit for accessing static data. In fact, in some cases it might be faster as you don't need to find it through class pointers.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I'll do some profiling with the array option and the bits option suggested in comments.

Comment: @Virus721: If I was doing this, I would use the bit flag or range comparison as mentioned elsewhere if that is an option. While I often use lookup tables similar to your first bit of code, if I could set it up so that, for example, the highest bit is set for the ones that must return true, I would certainly do that.

Comment: @JonathanWood Why would the switch require comparing each item? A switch is designed with a jump-table in mind using the enum as index.

Comment: @Jens So switch() is faster than if/else if/else chain ?

Comment: @Virus721: Not always, but it often is.

Comment: @Jens: Obviously, there could be different ways to implement a `switch` statement. All the ones I've seen used simply `if...else...` logic. To be honest, I'm not sure how `switch` could avoid comparing each item because the items may not be consecutive and how would that approach handle the `default` case? At any rate, I'm not saying it's impossible, but most `switch` statements I've seen do something very different.

Comment: @Jens: How could a `switch` statement handle the `default` case and/or cases where the switch values were not consecutive without comparing each value?

Comment: Actually i'll go for BSH's solution which is the fastest and is possible consdering what i need to do. My objects are going to be constructed and remain constant until destruction, so pre-computing the result of this function for all further accesses will be better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonathanWood: The switch statement with a jump table does a single range comparison (which is just one comparison if all valid alternatives are small positive integers, because it can used unsigned comparison) followed by a table lookup. Branch prediction will give you the range check for free.

Comment: @JonathanWood For a small type the compiler could simply create a jump table covering the complete value range, putting the default code for every skipped position. I found this http://741mhz.com/switch/ interesting. It has example with assembler code.

Comment: The array option could produce a cache miss. This could slow it down on many architectures. Also, as MikeSeymour pointed out, in some circumstances the switch will not require comparing each item. This question made me realize that I don't know the answer, though I would have favored using the array look up. The range comparison is interesting, but could accidentally be broken by maintenance modifications later.

Comment: @Jens: Yes, I can see it's practical when you have a small range of values. Of course, that is not always the case and is not necessarily the case here.

Comment: @AviBerger, A cache miss is certainly possible; but if the function is called often enough that the question of its optimization is raised, the array is _most probably_ in the cache.

Comment: A calculated jump, IIRC, implies emptying the processor's pipeline, and that is at least ten times slower than an array lookup, if that array is in the cache. Unless the array is a cache miss every time the function is called, I would go with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your enumeration is partitioned so that all the values that return true come before all the ones that return false, then you can do this:

```
inline bool isBinaryOper() const
{
   return this->_eType < E_LPARENT;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'll have more than one table like this. It might be ordered in one table but not in the other, so i'm not sure this is gonna be possible. Though spliting a qwitch into multple parts like this, to make some kind of binary search might help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that array lookup is very likely to be the most efficient thing. There's simply no "fat" in it for an optimizing compiler to trim off.

Of course, the table will most possibly be placed in other segment (.rdata instead of .text), and the table will therefore eat up more cache lines. However the chance that you will encounter any negative effect from that is negligible.

Of course, a compiler is likely to implement a `switch` with dense case values into a table lookup. That will give a huge improvement over the 'naïve' cascaded-if implementation. However, there is no guarantee that that will be done in the most straightforward way.

---

A very simple quick-and-dirty experiment corroborates my reasoning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

enum E
{
    E0,
    E1,
    E2,
    E3,
    E4,
    E5,
    E6,
    E7,
};

bool f1(E x)
{
    if (x > E7 || x < E0)
        throw "ohbadbad";

    static const bool t[] =
    {
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
    };

    return t[x];
}

bool f2(E x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case E0: return true;
    case E1: return true;
    case E2: return true;
    case E3: return true;
    case E4: return false;
    case E5: return false;
    case E6: return false;
    case E7: return false;
    default: throw "ohbadbad";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool (*f)(E) = (argc > 1 && argv[1][0] == 's')
        ? f2
        : f1;

    clock_t t = clock();

    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j)
            r += f((E)(j & E7));

    printf("%d %I64d\n", r, __int64(clock() - t));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with MSVC++ 16 for both x86 and x64 (with -O2 option), `f1` gives a more than 3 times better clock than `f2`.

Analyzing the object code, it is very easy to see why: the `switch` is indeed implemented using a table - but it is a table of labels. The code fetches an address from the table and then jumps to that address. One branch effectively does `return 0`, another `return 1`. Not only that is an unnecessary step, but also results in frequent branch mispredictions.

Comment: You could reformulate the switch statement to something like
`bool f2(E x) {
 bool result = false;
 switch(x) {
 case E0: result = true; break;
 // ...
 }
 return result;` Could you run this with your compiler? I just don't have one here right now.

Comment: @Jens, for x86 the difference became 35% instead of three-times. Then, because `f2` does not check its argument for validity, I also omitted argument control from `f1` to make the two functions fully equivalent. The difference raised insignificantly, to 36%. For x64  it is only 20% though!

Comment: The check is probably eliminated by branch prediction.