# Are switch-case constructs implemented as binary search?

Tags: compiler-construction, switch-statement

I'm wondering how a `switch`-`case` statement is implemented:

**Example**

say one has the following code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int v = sc.nextInt();
switch(v) {
    case 0 :
        System.out.println("Zero");
        break;
    case 1 :
        System.out.println("One");
        break;
    case 2 :
        System.out.println("Two");
        break;
    //...
    default :
        System.out.println("No one digit number");
}
```

One can implement this as:

```
if(v == 0) {
    System.out.println("Zero");
}
else if(v == 1) {
    System.out.println("One");
}
else if(v == 2) {
    System.out.println("Two");
}
//...
else {
    System.out.println("No one digit number");
}
```

But a more efficient program is:

```
if(v >= 0 && v <= 9) {
    if(v <= 5) {
        if(v <= 2) {
            if(v <= 1) {
                if(v == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Zero");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("One");
                }
            else {
                System.out.println("Two");
            }
        }
        //...
    }
    //...
}
else {
    System.out.println("No one digit number");
}
```

This can be important since there are programs (like compiler compilers) that write Java/C#/C++ source code and thus generate very large switch statements.

Comment: No; they use lookup tables.

Comment: Remember that implementation depends a lot on the compiler. Sometimes a single technique is used, sometimes another. Most optimized robust compilers are a combination trying to use the most optimal way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimization: Is the order of cases in a switch statement important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983964/optimization-is-the-order-of-cases-in-a-switch-statement-important)

Comment: @rici: I think the question differs, since it is merely a question how the compiler handles such statements, not how the language handles them: in some languages the order might be important of semantical reasons, but then there is still a discussion *how* the compiler implements a switch-case efficiently, and furthermore the question to which you link is closed :(.

Comment: @CommuSoft: All the languages mentioned have the same semantics in which order is not semantically important; the question is how the compiler handles it. And the answer is, "it depends". Which is the same as the answer to your question. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658402/c-function-static-local-performance/23658900#23658900 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129718/switch-optimization-for-many-cases-guarantees-equal-access-time-for-any-case/2129733#2129733 and probably many more.

Answer (score 9):

Switch/case statements are implemented with a combination of binary decision trees and jump tables, depending on the case ranges.

1. For simple switch statements (2 - 3 cases) it is often more efficient to emit simple if statement, depending on how dense the values are (1 2 3 vs 1 2 9 for example).
2. For larger cardinality switches with a single dense group, it is common to use a jump table based directly or indirectly on the test value.
3. With sparse groups, or mix of dense and sparse groups, binary decision trees are used to bisect the group lists and a jump table is used within the group (the leaf of tree).

So the answer is, yes, sometimes, but not that simple.

It is possible to fill in "empty" case slots with default jumps to allow construction of a dense range. For small branches, or branches against non-integer values switches are rewritten as if conditionals (such as languages that allow switching on strings or regular expressions). In your example, cases for digits 0-9 would certainly be encoded as a lookup table because it is a dense group.

In all cases, binary decision trees are an important part of emitting efficient switch / case constructs.

The .NET CLR even has an opcode that accepts jumptables, and it hides the handling of the default case, this allows the runtime to validate the code as safe without full flow analysis.

Comment: If lookup tables are used, should this enable the fact of using switch-case statements for all kinds of objects that support hashcodes? And not only literals? But something like `case new Person("James",25) :` Then such instances could be constructed at compile time and stored in the lookup table.

Comment: Theoretically yes, for the compiler to efficiently compile it, it has to be able to compress or map the hash values to a dense range (using modulo I suppose), so you'd have to provide a hash function that allowed this, plus the compiler would have to provide a hook. Else it is left with binary decision trees.

Comment: @CommuSoft - You've actually given me some incentive to try this in my Cola compiler. I am supporting integral values, strings and eventually regular expression patterns, but I like the idea of trying object based switching as well. I think I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @CommuSoft - General pattern matching support in languages like Scala and Haskell can "switch" on objects. I haven't looked at the implementations yet but it might be worth a glance since you are into compilers.

Answer (score 3):

The way switch statements are implemented depends on the 'case' list. When the set of 'case' is dense, a jump table can be used (like a `goto Label[v]` statement, if that existed). This is much faster than binary search.