# Fastest way to solve chain-calculations

Tags: c#, performance

I have a input like

```
string input = "14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34"; 
// up to 10MB string size

int result = Calc(input); // 11
```

- the calculation is from left to right, number by number
- the numbers are 0 to 99
- multiplication before addition is ignored so `14 + 2 * 32` is `512`
- the possible calculations are `+-*/`
- division by `0` is not possible so after a `/` can't be a `0`

My Approach

```
public static int Calc(string sInput)
{
    int iCurrent = sInput.IndexOf(' ');
    int iResult = int.Parse(sInput.Substring(0, iCurrent));
    int iNext = 0;
    while ((iNext = sInput.IndexOf(' ', iCurrent + 4)) != -1)
    {
        iResult = Operate(iResult, sInput[iCurrent + 1], int.Parse(sInput.Substring((iCurrent + 3), iNext - (iCurrent + 2))));
        iCurrent = iNext;
    }
    return Operate(iResult, sInput[iCurrent + 1], int.Parse(sInput.Substring((iCurrent + 3))));
}

public static int Operate(int iReturn, char cOperator, int iOperant)
{
    switch (cOperator)
    {
        case '+':
            return (iReturn + iOperant);
        case '-':
            return (iReturn - iOperant);
        case '*':
            return (iReturn * iOperant);
        case '/':
            return (iReturn / iOperant);
        default:
            throw new Exception("Error");
    }
}
```

I need the **fastest** way to get a result.

**Question:** is there a way to make this calculation faster? I have multiple threads but I use only one.

**Update:**

Test-Case: (I've removed the division by 0 bug and removed the `StringBuilder.ToString()` from the `StopWatch` measurement)

```
Random rand = new Random();
System.Text.StringBuilder input = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
string operators = "+-*/";
input.Append(rand.Next(0, 100));
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    int number = rand.Next(0, 100);
    char coperator = operators[rand.Next(0, number > 0 ? 4 : 3)];
    input.Append(" " + coperator + " " + number);
}
string calc = input.ToString();
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
int result = Calc(calc);
watch.Stop();
```

Comment: Your approach is currently wrong anyway. At present it outputs `0` for `5 + 2 * 0` when it should output `5`. You need to include the PEDMAS/BODMAS rules.

Comment: @john No, 0 is the correct answer here.

Comment: @john OP states _"point before line is ignored"_

Comment: @Fildor what does "point before line" mean?

Comment: "*", "/" = "Point" , "+", "-" = "Line" derived from the operators in "non-digital" writing. ( dot and : for mult/division)

Comment: @john it means the normal mathematical priority of operators is ignored

Comment: Apologies then, I've never heard that term before.

Comment: @john It probably has a more formal name but it would be common in German elementary schools to be taught as "Punkt vor Strich".

Comment: You can't process this with multiple threads as the divide operation isn't associative, it needs to be done sequentially. However, if you have control of the string format, consider using Reverse Polish Notation.

Comment: @Fildor probably a [google translation](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&ei=zUyyWszYLJGakwX7mrHYDA&q=punkt+vor+strich+english&oq=punkt+vor+strich+english&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1.6067423.6073668.0.6073844.19.17.0.0.0.0.467.2156.0j7j2j0j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..9.10.2153...0i67k1j0i131k1j0i131i67k1j0i10k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.z_ykormYV2M)

Comment: @MongZhu May well be. As a German the term of course made sense to me. It didn't even occur to me that this rule could _not_ be known by that term.

Comment: With such evaluation rules, in graph theory, the expression tree is a simple path. And since expression evaluation is basically traversing the tree bottoms-up, I cannot see how one could parallelize such process (as opposed to "regular" trees). So I don't think multi-threading is an option here, at least when it comes to evaluation. Parsing of the string however could be parallelized, I think.

Comment: cool that you posted a test case with time measurement (+1 for that). unfortunately it creates examples where you can devide by `0`.

Comment: FunFact: I just tried to find an "official" name for that rule. Even academic (Uni) lectures refer to it as "Punkt vor Strich" ("Dot before Line") :/ Best fit I found was "Preference of the higher valued operation" (translation mine - probably not really correct)

Comment: Thank you @FIldor . +1 for effort though :) At least if I see it again, I'll know now.

Comment: IMO the most important skill here - when the question is about performance - is: how to run the test. I've edited my answer to include full BenchmarkDotNet usage and results. This shows that my idea wasn't bad - it gives a 10* improvement. But from that starting point, you can add in *any other* ideas and compare them.

Comment: @Dr.Snail FYI I updated my test rig (and answer) to include correctness checking against much longer inputs - the results were varied - just: make sure you double check the **result** of any version you choose to take

Comment: @Fildor The English term is "order of precedence"

Comment: @MarcGravell the result from MiraiMann  is a different one I'll check that. Did you measure in Release or Debug?

Comment: @DavidG Thanks! Oh, I guess I mixed up "preference" and "precedence"

Comment: @Dr.Snail both :) performance numbers are from release, though

Comment: Do you need to handle negative numbers in the input?  Your current test code won't create those since your generator only generates positives, and you only put one operator between each number; but this will impact some solutions' handling of `"0 - -1"` with some giving `-1` (incorrect according to normal math and some `1`.

Comment: @Dr.Snail ah ok; apologies.

Comment: The fact that you’re expressing this as a list rather than a tree means you can’t easily use associativity to parallelize the operation. If you had only additions or only multiplications, or a balanced computation tree, you could divide and conquer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for improvements to working code, and so belongs on Code Review.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following solution is a finite automaton. Calc(input) = O(n). For better performance, this solution does not use `IndexOf`, `Substring`, `Parse`, string concatenation, or repeated reading of value (fetching `input[i]` more than once)... just a character processor.

```
    static int Calculate1(string input)
    {
        int acc = 0;
        char last = ' ', operation = '+';

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var current = input[i];
            switch (current)
            {
                case ' ':
                    if (last != ' ')
                    {
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case '+': acc += last - '0'; break;
                            case '-': acc -= last - '0'; break;
                            case '*': acc *= last - '0'; break;
                            case '/': acc /= last - '0'; break;
                        }

                        last = ' ';
                    }

                    break;

                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
                case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                    if (last == ' ') last = current;
                    else
                    {
                        var num = (last - '0') * 10 + (current - '0');
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case '+': acc += num; break;
                            case '-': acc -= num; break;
                            case '*': acc *= num; break;
                            case '/': acc /= num; break;
                        }
                        last = ' ';
                    }
                    break;

                case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
                    operation = current;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (last != ' ')
            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+': acc += last - '0'; break;
                case '-': acc -= last - '0'; break;
                case '*': acc *= last - '0'; break;
                case '/': acc /= last - '0'; break;
            }

        return acc;
    }
```

---

And another implementation. It reads 25% less from the input. I expect that it has 25% better performance.

```
    static int Calculate2(string input)
    {
        int acc = 0, i = 0;
        char last = ' ', operation = '+';

        while (i < input.Length)
        {
            var current = input[i];
            switch (current)
            {
                case ' ':
                    if (last != ' ')
                    {
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case '+': acc += last - '0'; break;
                            case '-': acc -= last - '0'; break;
                            case '*': acc *= last - '0'; break;
                            case '/': acc /= last - '0'; break;
                        }

                        last = ' ';
                        i++;
                    }

                    break;

                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
                case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                    if (last == ' ')
                    {
                        last = current;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var num = (last - '0') * 10 + (current - '0');
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case '+': acc += num; break;
                            case '-': acc -= num; break;
                            case '*': acc *= num; break;
                            case '/': acc /= num; break;
                        }

                        last = ' ';
                        i += 2;
                    }
                    break;

                case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
                    operation = current;
                    i += 2;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (last != ' ')
            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+': acc += last - '0'; break;
                case '-': acc -= last - '0'; break;
                case '*': acc *= last - '0'; break;
                case '/': acc /= last - '0'; break;
            }

        return acc;
    }
```

---

I implemented one more variant:

```
    static int Calculate3(string input)
    {
        int acc = 0, i = 0;
        var operation = '+';

        while (true)
        {
            var a = input[i++] - '0';
            if (i == input.Length)
            {
                switch (operation)
                {
                    case '+': acc += a; break;
                    case '-': acc -= a; break;
                    case '*': acc *= a; break;
                    case '/': acc /= a; break;
                }

                break;
            }

            var b = input[i];
            if (b == ' ') i++;
            else
            {
                a = a * 10 + (b - '0');
                i += 2;
            }

            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+': acc += a; break;
                case '-': acc -= a; break;
                case '*': acc *= a; break;
                case '/': acc /= a; break;
            }

            if (i >= input.Length) break;
            operation = input[i];
            i += 2;
        }

        return acc;
    }
```

Results in abstract points:

- Calculate1 230
- Calculate2 192
- Calculate3 111

Comment: I would use `foreach` instead of `for` *(when the string would be in already memory)*, but I'm not sure if it is faster. But universally I would prefer using `StreamReader` and read character *(when the input is file or some other stream)* to reduce memory load for big 'strings'. Otherwise my solution of this problem would be probably similar.

Comment: 'for' is faster than 'foreach'. We can load buffer by buffer and processing bytes of each. The current algorithm is actual in this case too.

Comment: FYI - I added your code to the `BenchmarkDotNet` results in my answer; looks really good

Comment: (unfortunately, it comes up with a different answer for real cases; I haven't debugged why)

Comment: Fun fact, if you make your switch statement with numbers (maybe ASCII codes) as far as I know, runtime will make binary search in order to find the most suitable case faster :)

Comment: @kuskmen `switch` is usually implemented as a simple jump-table; if there is a block of contiguous numbers that don't start with zero, it is usually implemented as a "subtract first number, *then* run a simple jump-table"; if you have a specific scenario you're thinking of where `switch` becomes a binary search, I'm very interested, but... that almost certainly wouldn't happen here. The main exception would be `switch(string)` which becomes a dictionary lookup *then* a jump-table, or the new switch conditions which become `if`

Comment: I think if he convert it to switch(int) and order the cases it will use binary search, I will try to search for the place I've seen this

Comment: @MarcGravell 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100473/Something-You-May-Not-Know-About-the-Switch-Statem
and maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26470395/3394884
nevertheless now that I've read other options seems like it will not be a dealbreaker.

Comment: @kuskmen fair enough; here's a [C# example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvKgzounAFgICyACgCUbDlwC+EzjIJoAdjAKRFNUXPaUuO+UvkEAvGSpydUAO5oYAYwAWBIWhFmuW3R4I3ocAsTx4IAQAZsSipATACHAQANYU2p463lC+9AFBwfThkdFxCUnJPgT0AKyBIdkiEVEx8a4eKb7lFaE5tfkNuk0EAOwZle159YmFXsW95ZlVNcMFY+OpBAAcA1lDdfNjPQCca2HVuZumo4UAJnDBEACuGKgh6ocdI0nSlF04vQR4WwRvOiQAGxEfhtESsf5cIEgwbgyGcaF8B6iCFUSRAA===) where it does indeed become binary search using `bgt.s`; I wonder if this is relatively new in Roslyn - I don't recall `csc` doing this *many years* ago when I last checked

Comment: @Dr.Snail Yes, My previous implementation had bug, but now it is fixed.

Comment: @MarcGravell My previous implementation had bug, but now it is fixed.  Can you check the performance of the new one (correct) implementation?

Comment: @MiraiMann already updated, verified, and perf test running :)

Comment: @MiraiMann done; you're still winning, but with the extra test, the difference is smaller

Comment: @MarcGravell I added one more implantation. Can you check it too, please?

Comment: @MiraiMann you're the fastest but still invalid result

Comment: @Dr.Snail I have only this test case 14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34 = 11. Can you give me some more cases, if you have? I think you can add them to question description it will be correct and useful.

Comment: @Dr.Snail your cases generator works incorrectly. It appends 'rand.Next(1, 100)' to end of the case. And as result, the last number in the generated case can be more than 99 (in 99 cases from 100). My algorithms don't cover this case. Please, remove this line.

Comment: @Dr.Snail Your generator appends the random number to the end of the case in the last iteration of the loop and after that appends one more number again. Please, check result of your generator.

Comment: @Dr.Snail right), my both algorithms worked wrong when case ends with single digit number. Fixed.

Comment: great job, 10 times faster compared to mine

Comment: @Dr.Snail Thanks) I have an idea how to solve this task by multithreading way but have no time to do it now. Tomorrow, I'll try to provide a better solution.

Comment: “'for' is faster than 'foreach'” — is that **still** the case? That would be incredibly poor from the C# compiler (or JIT, don’t care). It’s trivial to optimise. `foreach` on an array/string/… should be at least as fast as `for`, there’s no reason for it not to be.

Comment: @Dr.Snail I found an idea but had no time to implement it. But I schedule to do it today.

Comment: @MarcGravell , question now is if it is binary search is it actually faster?

Comment: @kuskmen you'd have to test it

Comment: Will do and will get back here :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, I implemented one more variant (twice as fast). Can you check it, please.

Comment: @Dr.Snail, I implemented one more variant (twice as fast than previous). I have problems with my multithreading implementation. Little bit wait, please.

Comment: fixed small defect (change i++ to i+=2) in last implementation. It can downgrade performance. Now have no ability to check.

Comment: @MiraiMann I don't think I have that test rig any more; best I can do is add a note

Answer (score 20):

Edit edit: updated with latest versions by The General and Mirai Mann:

If you want to know which horse is fastest: race the horses. Here are `BenchmarkDotNet` results comparing various answers from this question (I **have not** merged their code into my full example, because that feels wrong - only the numbers are presented) with repeatable but large random input, via:

```
static MyTests()
{
    Random rand = new Random(12345);
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    string operators = "+-*/";
    var lastOperator = '+';
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        var @operator = operators[rand.Next(0, 4)];
        input.Append(rand.Next(lastOperator == '/' ? 1 : 0, 100) + " " + @operator + " ");
        lastOperator = @operator;
    }
    input.Append(rand.Next(0, 100));
    expression = input.ToString();
}
private static readonly string expression;
```

with sanity checks (to check they all do the right thing):

```
Original: -1426
NoSubStrings: -1426
NoSubStringsUnsafe: -1426
TheGeneral4: -1426
MiraiMann1: -1426
```

we get timings (note: `Original` is OP's version in the question; `NoSubStrings[Unsafe]` is my versions from below, and two other versions from other answers by user-name):

(lower "Mean" is better)

(note; there is a **newer** version of Mirai Mann's implementation, but I no longer have things setup to run a new test; but: fair to assume it should be better!)

Runtime: .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2633.0

```
             Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
           Original | 104.11 ms | 1.4920 ms | 1.3226 ms |
       NoSubStrings |  21.99 ms | 0.4335 ms | 0.7122 ms |
 NoSubStringsUnsafe |  20.53 ms | 0.4103 ms | 0.6967 ms |
        TheGeneral4 |  15.50 ms | 0.3020 ms | 0.5369 ms |
         MiraiMann1 |  15.54 ms | 0.3096 ms | 0.4133 ms |
```

Runtime: .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2633.0

```
             Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |    Median |
------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
           Original | 114.15 ms | 1.3142 ms | 1.0974 ms | 114.13 ms |
       NoSubStrings |  21.33 ms | 0.4161 ms | 0.6354 ms |  20.93 ms |
 NoSubStringsUnsafe |  19.24 ms | 0.3832 ms | 0.5245 ms |  19.43 ms |
        TheGeneral4 |  13.97 ms | 0.2795 ms | 0.2745 ms |  13.86 ms |
         MiraiMann1 |  15.60 ms | 0.3090 ms | 0.4125 ms |  15.53 ms |
```

Runtime: .NET Core 2.1.0-preview1-26116-04 (CoreCLR 4.6.26116.03, CoreFX 4.6.26116.01), 64bit RyuJIT

```
             Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |    Median |
------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
           Original | 101.51 ms | 1.7807 ms | 1.5786 ms | 101.44 ms |
       NoSubStrings |  21.36 ms | 0.4281 ms | 0.5414 ms |  21.07 ms |
 NoSubStringsUnsafe |  19.85 ms | 0.4172 ms | 0.6737 ms |  19.80 ms |
        TheGeneral4 |  14.06 ms | 0.2788 ms | 0.3723 ms |  13.82 ms |
         MiraiMann1 |  15.88 ms | 0.3153 ms | 0.5922 ms |  15.45 ms |
```

---

### Original answer from before I added `BenchmarkDotNet`:

If I was trying this, I'd be **tempted** to have a look at the `Span<T>` work in 2.1 previews - the point being that a `Span<T>` can be sliced without allocating (and a `string` can be converted to a `Span<char>` without allocating); this would allow the string carving and parsing to be performed without any allocations. However, reducing allocations is *not always* quite the same thing as raw performance (although they are related), so to know if it was faster: you'd need to race your horses (i.e. compare them).

If `Span<T>` isn't an option: you can still do the same thing by tracking an `int offset` manually and just *never using `SubString`)

In either case (`string` or `Span<char>`): if your operation only needs to cope with a certain subset of representations of integers, I might be tempted to hand role a custom `int.Parse` equivalent that doesn't apply as many rules (cultures, alternative layouts, etc), and which works without needing a `Substring` - for example it could take a `string` and `ref int offset`, where the `offset` is updated to be *where the parse stopped* (either because it hit an operator or a space), and which worked.

Something like:

```
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34";

        var val = Evaluate(input);
        System.Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
    static int Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        SkipSpaces(expression, ref offset);
        int value = ReadInt32(expression, ref offset);
        while(ReadNext(expression, ref offset, out char @operator, out int operand))
        {
            switch(@operator)
            {
                case '+': value = value + operand; break;
                case '-': value = value - operand; break;
                case '*': value = value * operand; break;
                case '/': value = value / operand; break;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    static bool ReadNext(string value, ref int offset,
        out char @operator, out int operand)
    {
        SkipSpaces(value, ref offset);

        if(offset >= value.Length)
        {
            @operator = (char)0;
            operand = 0;
            return false;
        }

        @operator = value[offset++];
        SkipSpaces(value, ref offset);

        if (offset >= value.Length)
        {
            operand = 0;
            return false;
        }
        operand = ReadInt32(value, ref offset);
        return true;
    }

    static void SkipSpaces(string value, ref int offset)
    {
        while (offset < value.Length && value[offset] == ' ') offset++;
    }
    static int ReadInt32(string value, ref int offset)
    {
        bool isNeg = false;
        char c = value[offset++];
        int i = (c - '0');
        if(c == '-')
        {
            isNeg = true;
            i = 0;
            // todo: what to do here if `-` is not followed by [0-9]?
        }

        while (offset < value.Length && (c = value[offset++]) >= '0' && c <= '9')
            i = (i * 10) + (c - '0');
        return isNeg ? -i : i;
    }
}
```

Next, I might consider whether it is worthwhile switching to `unsafe` to remove the double length checks. So I'd implement it *both ways*, and test it with something like BenchmarkDotNet to see whether it is worth it.

---

Edit: here is is with `unsafe` added and BenchmarkDotNet usage:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyTests>();
        System.Console.WriteLine(summary);
    }

}
public class MyTests
{
    const string expression = "14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34";
    [Benchmark]
    public int Original() => EvalOriginal.Calc(expression);
    [Benchmark]
    public int NoSubStrings() => EvalNoSubStrings.Evaluate(expression);
    [Benchmark]
    public int NoSubStringsUnsafe() => EvalNoSubStringsUnsafe.Evaluate(expression);
}
static class EvalOriginal
{
    public static int Calc(string sInput)
    {
        int iCurrent = sInput.IndexOf(' ');
        int iResult = int.Parse(sInput.Substring(0, iCurrent));
        int iNext = 0;
        while ((iNext = sInput.IndexOf(' ', iCurrent + 4)) != -1)
        {
            iResult = Operate(iResult, sInput[iCurrent + 1], int.Parse(sInput.Substring((iCurrent + 3), iNext - (iCurrent + 2))));
            iCurrent = iNext;
        }
        return Operate(iResult, sInput[iCurrent + 1], int.Parse(sInput.Substring((iCurrent + 3))));
    }

    public static int Operate(int iReturn, char cOperator, int iOperant)
    {
        switch (cOperator)
        {
            case '+':
                return (iReturn + iOperant);
            case '-':
                return (iReturn - iOperant);
            case '*':
                return (iReturn * iOperant);
            case '/':
                return (iReturn / iOperant);
            default:
                throw new Exception("Error");
        }
    }
}
static class EvalNoSubStrings {
    public static int Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        SkipSpaces(expression, ref offset);
        int value = ReadInt32(expression, ref offset);
        while (ReadNext(expression, ref offset, out char @operator, out int operand))
        {
            switch (@operator)
            {
                case '+': value = value + operand; break;
                case '-': value = value - operand; break;
                case '*': value = value * operand; break;
                case '/': value = value / operand; break;
                default: throw new Exception("Error");
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    static bool ReadNext(string value, ref int offset,
        out char @operator, out int operand)
    {
        SkipSpaces(value, ref offset);

        if (offset >= value.Length)
        {
            @operator = (char)0;
            operand = 0;
            return false;
        }

        @operator = value[offset++];
        SkipSpaces(value, ref offset);

        if (offset >= value.Length)
        {
            operand = 0;
            return false;
        }
        operand = ReadInt32(value, ref offset);
        return true;
    }

    static void SkipSpaces(string value, ref int offset)
    {
        while (offset < value.Length && value[offset] == ' ') offset++;
    }
    static int ReadInt32(string value, ref int offset)
    {
        bool isNeg = false;
        char c = value[offset++];
        int i = (c - '0');
        if (c == '-')
        {
            isNeg = true;
            i = 0;
        }

        while (offset < value.Length && (c = value[offset++]) >= '0' && c <= '9')
            i = (i * 10) + (c - '0');
        return isNeg ? -i : i;
    }
}

static unsafe class EvalNoSubStringsUnsafe
{
    public static int Evaluate(string expression)
    {

        fixed (char* ptr = expression)
        {
            int len = expression.Length;
            var c = ptr;
            SkipSpaces(ref c, ref len);
            int value = ReadInt32(ref c, ref len);
            while (len > 0 && ReadNext(ref c, ref len, out char @operator, out int operand))
            {
                switch (@operator)
                {
                    case '+': value = value + operand; break;
                    case '-': value = value - operand; break;
                    case '*': value = value * operand; break;
                    case '/': value = value / operand; break;
                    default: throw new Exception("Error");
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    static bool ReadNext(ref char* c, ref int len,
        out char @operator, out int operand)
    {
        SkipSpaces(ref c, ref len);

        if (len-- == 0)
        {
            @operator = (char)0;
            operand = 0;
            return false;
        }
        @operator = *c++;
        SkipSpaces(ref c, ref len);

        if (len == 0)
        {
            operand = 0;
            return false;
        }
        operand = ReadInt32(ref c, ref len);
        return true;
    }

    static void SkipSpaces(ref char* c, ref int len)
    {
        while (len != 0 && *c == ' ') { c++;len--; }
    }
    static int ReadInt32(ref char* c, ref int len)
    {
        bool isNeg = false;
        char ch = *c++;
        len--;
        int i = (ch - '0');
        if (ch == '-')
        {
            isNeg = true;
            i = 0;
        }

        while (len-- != 0 && (ch = *c++) >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            i = (i * 10) + (ch - '0');
        return isNeg ? -i : i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Linq-comment. I guess I was tempted to go the "convinient" way. :) Thanx for the lesson.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to emit instructions? Then all the runtime/processor optimizations can occur? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @kuskmen not unless the expression is going to be the same over and over and over; emit is actually *slooooow* - it only becomes fast when you can cache the emitted IL and re-use it lots and lots of times for different inputs, which *doesn't apply here*. There's no point storing generated IL per expression in a cache - by the time you've done that, you might as well store the *result* per expression.

Comment: Hah awesome, my jedi anti-optimizing skills are to be feared !

Comment: @TheGeneral I anti-optimize things *all the time* (by accident); the important thing is: having tools like BenchmarkDotNet so that we notice :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, yea actually that's what I was thinking if we can solve the problem a bit differently, but I guess in this specific case is overkill, as you said if we repeatedly use this expression is another thing...

Comment: I did a cross-platform comparison with [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437081/1129332) implementation of this solution, and Java is about 20 times faster. Oops...

Comment: @MarcGravell i know this horse has bolted, but if you have that test code around, id be honoured if you could include my results in your table,

Comment: @TheGeneral good news; it looks like you've taken a slim lead

Comment: Wow, I wonder why my bencharks turned out so diffrent! Anyway all good. I'm stoked I managed to get it down! Thanks for that again

Answer (score 6):

## NOTE

Per comments, this answer does not give a performant solution.
I'll leave it here as there are points to be considered / which may be of interest to others finding this thread in future; but as people have said below, this is far from the most performant solution.

---

### Original Answer

The .net framework already supplies a way to handle formulas given as strings:

```
var formula = "14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34";
var result = new DataTable().Compute(formula, null);
Console.WriteLine(result); //returns 139.125490196078
```

---

### Initial feedback based on comments

Per the comments thread I need to point out some things:

#### Does this work the way I've described?

No; this follows the normal rules of maths.

I assume that your amended rules are to simplify writing code to handle them, rather than because you want to support a new branch of mathematics?  If that's the case, I'd argue against that.  People will expect things to behave in a certain way; so you'd have to ensure that anyone sending equations to your code was primed with the knowledge to expect the rules of this new-maths rather than being able to use their existing expectations.

There isn't an option to change the rules here; so if your requirement is to change the rules of maths, this won't work for you.

#### Is this the Fastest Solution

No.  However it should perform well given MS spend a lot of time optimising their code, and so will likely perform faster than any hand-rolled code to do the same (though admittedly this code does a lot more than just support the four main operators; so it's not doing exactly the same).

Per MatthewWatson's specific comment (i.e. calling the DataTable constructor incurs a significant overhead) you'd want to create and then re-use one instance of this object.  Depending on what your solution looks like there are various ways to do that; here's one:

```
interface ICalculator //if we use an interface we can easily switch from datatable to some other calulator; useful for testing, or if we wanted to compare different calculators without much recoding
{
    T Calculate<T>(string expression) where T: struct;
}
class DataTableCalculator: ICalculator 
{
    readonly DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    public DataTableCalculator(){}
    public T Calculate<T>(string expression) where T: struct =>
        (T)dataTable.Compute(expression, null);
}

class Calculator: ICalculator
{
    static ICalculator internalInstance;
    public Calculator(){}
    public void InitialiseCalculator (ICalculator calculator)
    {
        if (internalInstance != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Calculator has already been initialised");
        }
        internalInstance = calculator;
    }
    public T Calculate<T>(string expression) where T: struct =>
        internalInstance.Calculate<T>(expression);
}

//then we use it on our code
void Main()
{
    var calculator1 = new Calculator();
    calculator1.InitialiseCalculator(new DataTableCalculator());
    var equation = "14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34"; 
    Console.WriteLine(calculator1.Calculate<double>(equation)); //139.125490196078
    equation = "1 + 2 - 3 + 4";
    Console.WriteLine(calculator1.Calculate<int>(equation)); //4
    calculator1 = null;
    System.GC.Collect(); //in reality we'd pretty much never do this, but just to illustrate that our static variable continues fro the life of the app domain rather than the life of the instance
    var calculator2 = new Calculator();
    //calculator2.InitialiseCalculator(new DataTableCalculator()); //uncomment this and you'll get an error; i.e. the calulator should only be initialised once.
    equation = "1 + 2 - 3 + 4 / 5 * 6 - 7 / 8 + 9";
    Console.WriteLine(calculator2.Calculate<double>(equation)); //12.925
}
```

NB: The above solution uses a static variable; some people are against use of statics.  For this scenario (i.e. where during the lifetime of the application you're only going to require one way of doing calculations) this is a legitimate use case.  If you wanted to support switching the calculator at runtime a different approach would be required.

---

### Update after Testing & Comparing

Having run some performance tests:

- The `DataTable.Compute` method's biggest problem is that for equations the size of which you're dealing with it throws a `StackOverflowException`; (i.e. based on your equation generator's loop `for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)`.
- For a single operation with a smaller equation (`i < 1000`), the compute method (including constructor and `Convert.ToInt32` on the `double` result) takes almost 100 times longer.
- for the single operation I also encountered overflow exceptions more often; i.e. because the result of the operations had pushed the value outside the bounds of supported data types...
- Even if we move the constructor/initialise call outside of the timed area and remove the conversion to int (and run for thousands of iterations to get an average), your solution comes in 3.5 times faster than mine.

Link to the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If you're not sure it's faster, why add as an answer?

Comment: `Compute` calculates according to mathematical rules of operator prioritization. This does not work according to OP: `var formula = "5 + 2 * 0";` should result in `0` and not `5`

Comment: I seriously doubt that will be quicker... The default constructor itself creates 4 collections, a RecordManager and a DataRowBuilder.

Comment: @DavidG The question asks for "the fastest".  I doubt anyone can provide a solution that's guaranteed to be the fastest; only say that something performs well.  They key here is that generally it's a bad idea to try to write your own code for something the framework provides; especially for something as complex as handling equations.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Speed actually isn't the point with this answer because it will not give the expected results. Computation in the suggested way does not take into account rules that contradict the common mathematical rules but are required in the assignment.

Comment: @MongZhu.  My impression had been that the non-maths rules were a way to simplify the requirements.  I'd argue that having to change the rules of maths to make it easier to code something's probably the wrong approach; especially when there's something which does it for you.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Good point if you're creating a new object every time; but that's not required; you can instantiate once then keep in memory.

Comment: All - Whilst I've said things about your comments here I agree I didn't express such in my answer; amending now to clarify.

Comment: (comment in favor of this answer) While I agree "fastest" is not a well-defined term in most of problems (including this one), OP has specified that in his question that a "faster" way is needed than it's current implementation. OP hasn't given any benchmark though, only the indication that the input string is several MB long. But anyway (and now comment *against* this answer), OP explicitly gave the constraint that all operations should be done sequentially, ignoring math rules.

Comment: Referring to your answer to MongZhu: Did it occur to you this could be an assignment to learn how to code, not to get the actual mathematically correct result? Learning to follow requirements that go against what you think is "right" is a valuable lesson, imho. (Although I doubt that is intended here).

Comment: @Pac0 1) Thanks.  2) Agreed but see response to MongZhu.

Comment: @Fildor. No it didn't.

Comment: Well, I have to admit that it is not stated in the OP explicitly that it _is_ an assignment. That's why I did not dv. I just inferred that by the way requirements are presented and it sounds pretty familiar - like an assignment we were given in 1st semester ("back then" in the 90s haha)

Comment: Just ran the metrics; agreed there are a number of issues with this solution (though leaving it up here as there is still some validity to it).

Answer (score 3):

## Update

My original answer was just a bit of fun late at night trying to put this in `unsafe` and I failed miserably (actually didn't work at all and was slower). However I decided to give this another shot.

The premise was to make everything inline, to remove as much `IL` as I could, keep everything in `int` or `char*`, and make my code pretty. I further optimized this by removing the switch, `Ifs` will be more efficient in this situation, also we can order them in the most logical way. And lastly, if we remove the amount of checks for things we do and assume the input is correct we can remove even more overhead by just assuming things like; if the `char` is > `'0'` it must be a number. If it's a space we can do some calculations, else it must be an operator.

This is my last attempt with 10,000,000 calculations run 100 times to get an average, each test does a `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` so we aren't fragmenting the memory.

**Results**

```
Test                          : ms    : Cycles (rough) : Increase
-------------------------------------------------------------------
OriginalCalc                  : 1,295 : 4,407,795,584  :
MarcEvalNoSubStrings          :   241 :   820,660,220  : 437.34%, * 5.32
MarcEvalNoSubStringsUnsafe    :   206 :   701,980,373  : 528.64%, * 6.28
MiraiMannCalc1                :   225 :   765,678,062  : 475.55%, * 5.75
MiraiMannCalc2                :   183 :   623,384,924  : 607.65%, * 7.07
MyCalc4                       :   156 :   534,190,325  : 730.12%, * 8.30
MyCalc5                       :   146 :   496,185,459  : 786.98%, * 8.86
MyCalc6                       :   134 :   455,610,410  : 866.41%, * 9.66
```

Fastest Code so far

```
unsafe int Calc6(ref string expression)
{
   int res = 0, val = 0, op = 0;
   var isOp = false;

   // pin the array
   fixed (char* p = expression)
   {
      // Let's not evaluate this 100 million times
      var max = p + expression.Length;

      // Let's go straight to the source and just increment the pointer
      for (var i = p; i < max; i++)
      {
         // numbers are the most common thing so let's do a loose
         // basic check for them and push them in to our val
         if (*i >= '0') { val = val * 10 + *i - 48; continue; }

         // The second most common thing are spaces
         if (*i == ' ')
         {
            // not every space we need to calculate
            if (!(isOp = !isOp)) continue;

            // In this case 4 ifs are more efficient then a switch
            // do the calculation, reset out val and jump out
            if (op == '+') { res += val; val = 0; continue; }
            if (op == '-') { res -= val; val = 0; continue; }
            if (op == '*') { res *= val; val = 0; continue; }
            if (op == '/') { res /= val; val = 0; continue; }

            // this is just for the first op
            res = val; val = 0; continue;                
         }
         // anything else is considered an operator
         op = *i;
      }

      if (op == '+') return res + val;
      if (op == '-') return res - val;
      if (op == '*') return res * val;
      if (op == '/') return res / val;

      throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
   }
}
```

**Previous**

```
unsafe int Calc4(ref string expression)
{
   int res = 0, val = 0, op = 0;
   var isOp = false;

   fixed (char* p = expression)
   {
      var max = p + expression.Length;
      for (var i = p; i < max; i++)
         switch (*i)
         {               
            case ' ':
               isOp = !isOp;
               if (!isOp) continue;    
               switch (op)
               {
                  case '+': res += val; val = 0; continue;
                  case '-': res -= val; val = 0; continue;
                  case '*': res *= val; val = 0; continue;
                  case '/': res /= val; val = 0; continue;
                  default: res = val; val = 0;  continue;
               }
            case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': op = *i; continue;
            default: val = val * 10 + *i - 48; continue;
         }

      switch (op)
      {
         case '+': return res + val;
         case '-': return res - val;
         case '*': return res * val;
         case '/': return res / val;
         default : return -1;
      }
   }
}
```

How I measured the *Thread* cycles

```
static class NativeMethods {
    public static ulong GetThreadCycles() {
        ulong cycles;
        if (!QueryThreadCycleTime(PseudoHandle, out cycles))
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        return cycles;
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool QueryThreadCycleTime(IntPtr hThread, out ulong cycles);
    private static readonly IntPtr PseudoHandle = (IntPtr)(-2);

}
```

## Original Post

I thought I'd try to be smart and use fixed and max this out with millions of calculations

```
public static unsafe int Calc2(string sInput)
{
   var buf = "";
   var start = sInput.IndexOf(' ');
   var value1 = int.Parse(sInput.Substring(0, start));
   string op = null;
   var iResult = 0;
   var isOp = false;
   fixed (char* p = sInput)
   {
      for (var i = start + 1; i < sInput.Length; i++)
      {
         var cur = *(p + i);
         if (cur == ' ')
         {
            if (!isOp)
            {
               op = buf;
               isOp = true;
            }
            else
            {
               var value2 = int.Parse(buf);
               switch (op[0])
               {
                  case '+': iResult += value1 + value2; break;
                  case '-': iResult += value1 - value2; break;
                  case '*': iResult += value1 * value2; break;
                  case '/': iResult += value1 / value2; break;
               }

               value1 = value2;
               isOp = false;
            }

            buf = "";
         }
         else
         {
            buf += cur;
         }
      }
   }

   return iResult;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var input = "14 + 2 * 32 / 60 + 43 - 7 + 3 - 1 + 0 * 7 + 87 - 32 / 34";
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append(input);
   for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
      sb.Append(" + " + input);

   var sw = new Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();

   Calc2(sb.ToString());

   sw.Stop();

   Console.WriteLine($"sw : {sw.Elapsed:c}");
}
```

Results were 2 seconds slower than the original!

Comment: IMO you're mainly testing the performance of `StringBuilder` here

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah no free lunch for me today, that's for sure

Comment: I'm going to hack in all the viable approaches I can see in the question/answers and put them all into a single BenchmarkDotNet runner; that should allow OP to compare all the ideas

Comment: @MarcGravell sounds like a plan

Comment: done; it came out very similar to the original - probably because it still uses a lot of parse/substring

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java fun fact. I implemented the same thing in Java and it runs about 20 times faster than [Mirai Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424758/1129332) implementation in C#. On my machine 100M chars input string took about 353 milliseconds.

Below is the code that creates and tests the result.

Also, note that while it's a good Java/C# performance tester this is not an optimal solution. A better performance can be achieved by multithreading it. It's possible to calculate portions of the string and then combine the result.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String...args){
        new Test().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(123);
        int result = 0;
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
        input.append(random.nextInt(99) + 1);
        while (input.length() < 100_000_000){
            int value = random.nextInt(100);
            switch (random.nextInt(4)){
                case 0:
                    input.append("-");
                    result -= value;
                    break;
                case 1: // +
                    input.append("+");
                    result += value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    input.append("*");
                    result *= value;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    input.append("/");
                    while (value == 0){
                        value = random.nextInt(100);
                    }
                    result /= value;
                    break;
            }
            input.append(value);
        }
        String inputData = input.toString();
        System.out.println("Test created in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int testResult = test(inputData);
        System.out.println("Completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

        if(result != testResult){
            throw new Error("Oops");
        }
    }

    private int test(String inputData) {
        char[] input;
        try {
            Field val = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
            val.setAccessible(true);
            input = (char[]) val.get(inputData);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
        int result = 0;
        int startingI = 1;
        {
            char c = input[0];
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                result += c - '0';
                c = input[1];
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                    result += (c - '0') * 10;
                    startingI++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = startingI, length = input.length, value=0; i < length; i++) {
            char operation = input[i];
            i++;
            char c = input[i];
            if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                value += c - '0';
                c = input[i + 1];
                if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                    value = value * 10 + (c - '0');
                    i++;
                }
            }
            switch (operation){
                case '-':
                    result -= value;
                    break;
                case '+':
                    result += value;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result *= value;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result /= value;
                    break;
            }
            value = 0;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

When you read the code then you can see that I used a small hack when converting the string to a char array. I mutated the string in order to avoid additional memory allocations for the char array.